# Postresql 9.3 replication not starting after pg_basebackup completes

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create a hot_standby server, and I receive the following error after pg_basebackup completes. Notice I use a shell script, replicator.sh, to start the replication. Can anyone give me some insight?

My specs:

- Debian Wheezy 7.6
- Postgresql 9.3
- Database size: ~115GB

Error:

```
postgres@database-master:/etc/postgresql/9.3/main$ sh replicator.sh
Stopping PostgreSQL
[ ok ] Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server: main.
Cleaning up old cluster directory
Starting base backup as replicator
Password:

113720266/113720266 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace

NOTICE: WAL archiving is not enabled; you must ensure that all required WAL segments are copied through other means to complete the backup
pg_basebackup: base backup completed
Starting Postgresql
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server failed to start.   
Please check the log output: 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC LOG: database system was interrupted; last 
known up at 2014-09-11 16:54:29 UTC 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC LOG: creating missing WAL directory 
"pg_xlog/archive_status" 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC LOG: incomplete startup packet 2014-09-11 17:56:33 
UTC LOG: invalid checkpoint record 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC FATAL: could not locate required 
checkpoint record 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC HINT: If you are not restoring from a backup, try 
removing the file "/var/lib/p[FAILesql/9.3/main/backup_label". 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC LOG: startup 
process (PID 21972) exited with exit code 1 2014-09-11 17:56:33 UTC LOG: aborting startup due to 
startup process failure ... failed! failed!
```

Contents of replicator.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Stopping PostgreSQL
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop

echo Cleaning up old cluster directory
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main

echo Starting base backup as replicator
pg_basebackup -h 123.456.789.123 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -U replicator -v -P

echo Writing recovery.conf file
sudo -u postgres bash -c "cat > /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/recovery.conf <<- _EOF1_
  standby_mode = 'on'
  primary_conninfo = 'host=123.456.789.123 port=5432  user=replicator password=XXXXX sslmode=require'
  trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger'
_EOF1_
"

echo Starting Postgresql
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Thank you,
Jake

Comment: Show the contents of `replicator.sh` please.

Comment: @CraigRinger replicator.sh added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess from the above is that the `pg_basebackup` failed and your shell script doesn't check for error return codes or use `set -e` to automatically abort after errors, so it just carried on regardless.

It's also possible that you don't have WAL archiving configured, or don't have a `restore_command` set in the replica. In that case, the transaction logs required to start the base backup will not be available and startup will fail.

I strongly recommend that you:

- Use `pg_basebackup -X stream` so that the required transaction logs get copied along with the backup; and
- Use `set -e` in your shell script, or test for errors with a suitable `if ! pg_basebackup .... ; then` block.